# From CSV file (latitude and longitude fields) to point .shp

Tags: qgis, vector, qgis-plugins, attribute-table, csv

How i create a new point shapefile from CSV table?

If i have a CSV file with a latitude and longitude fields, is there a method for to have in output a puntal shapefile?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use QGIS' [Delimited Text Layer](http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/importing_spreadsheets_csv.html) support to add the layer to the map, at which point you can right-click the layer and select 'Save As...' to convert to Shapefile or other supported formats.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not have qgis installed, still you can do it online. [Point2Poly](http://geospatialearth.in/Point2Poly)

You need to browse your csv file and select the latitude and longitude fields, then generate the shapefile.